# Is there a way to programatically close a menuitem in WPF

Tags: wpf, menu, menuitem

I have a menu in wpf that has an input box and a button on it.  Once the user clicks the button I need to close the menu.

Is there a way to do this?

```
    <Menu x:Name="MainMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Main">
            <MenuItem Header="SubMenu" x:Name="SubMenu">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Width="50" x:Name="TextBox" />
                    <Button Content="Click Me and Close" x:Name="Button" IsDefault="True"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
```

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get hold of the `MenuItem` and do:

```
_menuItem.IsSubmenuOpen = false;
```

Easy way to get hold of it:

```
<Button x:Name="_button" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}, AncestorLevel=2}"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
_button.Click += delegate
{
    (_button.Tag as MenuItem).IsSubmenuOpen = false;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I find that using `IsSubmenuOpen` doesn't properly eliminate focus from the Menu containing the `MenuItem` (especially if the Menu is in a ToolBar - the top-level `MenuItem` remains `Selected` even though the menu is "Closed"). I find sending a `MouseUp` event to the `MenuItem` works better (in the button's, or nested control's, Click event handler):

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
           Button b = sender as Button;

           if (b == null || !(b.Parent is MenuItem))
              return;

           MenuItem mi = b.Parent as MenuItem;

           mi.RaiseEvent(
              new MouseButtonEventArgs(
                 Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left
              ) 
              {RoutedEvent=Mouse.MouseUpEvent}
           );
        }
```

Comment: I've gone through the code with .NET Reflector and Steve is correct.  Setting the IsSubmenuOpen leaves an internal variable called MenuMode in an intermediate state. The end effect is that the Menu still has the focus and hovering over top level menu headers will cause the drop down to appear.  It appears that sending the MouseUp event will properly reset the internal states that the Menu control maintains.

Answer (score 2):

Steve thanks for your solution. That is actually right answer, and finally something that really works beside of tons of bad answers over the internet. I have a shorter (and more safe) solution based on your anwser. Because direct parent (e.Parent) of the button is not always MenuItem (from original answer that is StackPanel), your solution will not work. So just set the Name property of the MenuItem (Name="MyMenuItem") and hook this handler on the Button:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        MyMenuItem.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left) {
            RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseUpEvent
        });
    }
```