# Button in contextMenu menuItem

Tags: wpf, menu, contextmenu

I have a problem - in code behind I add collection of `MenuItems`, one of them has a `StackPanel` as its `Header`. There is a `Button` in `StackPanel` which is supposed to close the whole `ContextMenu`, but unfortunately it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Code sample:

```
var itemB = new MenuItem();
var stackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
var textBox = new TextBox() { Width = 60 };
var button = new Button() { Content = "Ok", Width = 60 };
stackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);
stackPanel.Children.Add(button);
itemB.Header = stackPanel;

//1st approach - doesn't work, I can only get access to MenuItem Header
button.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
    while (fe != null)
    {
        if (fe is ContextMenu)
        {
            (fe as ContextMenu).IsOpen = false;
            break;
        }
        fe = fe.Parent as FrameworkElement;
    }
};

//2nd approach - doesn't work, I can only get access to MenuItem Header
itemB.PreviewMouseUp += (sender, e) =>
{
    ((MenuItem)((MenuItem)sender).Parent).IsSubmenuOpen = false;
};
```

I have found similar articles, but no success:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17603d7e-b76b-45b5-a2df-2f3b378b690c/force-button-inside-contextmenu-to-close-contextmenu?forum=wpf

[WPF: button inside MenuItem, closing the menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204234/wpf-button-inside-menuitem-closing-the-menu)

[Is there a way to programatically close a menuitem in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782110/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-close-a-menuitem-in-wpf)

Comment: Any news? I've posted an answer, I'd like to know if it works for you or if you've found another solution.

Comment: @Massimiliano Hi! Thank you for the answer. This way it works, but in my case ContextMenu is defined in xaml and it it should stay there if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You said that the `ContextMenu` is defined on XAML, so let's suppose a code like this one:

```xml
<Grid>
  <Grid.ContextMenu>
    <!-- ContextMenu with a Name to be called! -->
    <ContextMenu Name="GridContextMenu"/>
  </Grid.ContextMenu>
  <Button Content="Open Menu" Click="Button_Click"/>
  <!-- other controls ... -->
</Grid>
```

Let's implement the click event:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox { Width = 60 };

    var button = new Button { Content = "Ok", Width = 60 };

    var stackPanel = new StackPanel
    {
        Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
        Children = { textBox, button },
    };

    var menuItem = new MenuItem
    {
        Header = stackPanel,
    };

    button.Click += (s, args) =>
    {
        GridContextMenu.IsOpen = false;
        GridContextMenu.Items.Remove(menuItem);
    };

    GridContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);

    GridContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```